# let $X$,$Y$ be independent Poisson distributed random variables with parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. $E(XY)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

$$E(XY) = \sum_{x,y} xy f(x,y),$$

but I don´t have the $f(x,y)$. $X+Y$ would be Poisson distributed with parameter $\alpha + \beta$, but what about $XY$? Not sure what else to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  Answer = $\alpha \beta$.  Can you derive it?

Comment: In the case of independent rv's the expectation of the product equals the product of the expectations. Or do you have the prove that in this special case?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}=f_Xf_Y$ i.e. it is the product of the marginal PDFs.

Thus - 
\begin{align}
E(XY)&=\int\int XYf_{X,Y}\\
&=\int\int XYf_Xf_Y\\
&=\int Xf_X \int Yf_Y\\
&=E(x)E(Y)
\end{align}
This holds for *any* independent $X$, $Y$, and not just Poisson variables. Similarly, this can be generalized to $n$ variables.